# Trigger SSJS when you open a link

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have portal xpage that has a couple of links. When the user opens a link i want to call some SSJS to log which link the user has clicked.

So far i tried to do it with an onclick event of the link but the problem with that is that window.open is going to be blocked by popup blockers.

Anybody any ideas how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can run your SSJS as usual. Add a CSJS code into `oncomplete` property of your event handler within the link...

```
<xp:link ....>
....
  <xp:eventHandler oncomplete="location.href='http://...url...'">
  ... other stuff ...
  </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

That will make sure your SSJS code runs before the client moves out the page.

**UPDATE:**

If the target page will be opened on a new tab and window.open is blocked by pop-up blockers, there is one option to run SSJS code via an additional Ajax request to an XAgent. We have implemented such a solution on OpenNTF Collaboration Today site and Niklas Heidloff explains how it works in a NotesIn9 video:

http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/09/25/notesin9-078-xpages-and-counting-clicks/

In a [custom control](https://github.com/OpenNTF/collaborationtoday/blob/master/disk-collaborationtoday/CustomControls/newsEntry.xsp) where we display links to the content, we run a CSJS function `logClick()` which runs just before the navigation:

```
<xp:link 
    value="#{javascript:compositeData.link}"
    text="#{javascript:compositeData.title}"
    target="_blank" 
    id="link6">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var baseUrl = "#{javascript:var baseUrl = context.getUrl().toString();baseUrl = baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.indexOf('.nsf')+4);baseUrl }";
            var url = baseUrl + "/log.xsp?" + "nid=" + "#{javascript:compositeData.nID}";                       
            logClick(url);      
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

`logClick()` function is defined in the [layout custom control](https://github.com/OpenNTF/collaborationtoday/blob/cfdd4727cb0f9e6cb7b3903a6ad733ee8302da9d/disk-collaborationtoday/CustomControls/layout.xsp) and it simply throw an Ajax request. If you notice, we are preparing the url in `log.xsp?nid=ID_OF_ENTRY`. [log.xsp](https://github.com/OpenNTF/collaborationtoday/blob/master/disk-collaborationtoday/XPages/log.xsp) is an XAgent and it takes the id data and save the 'clicked' event. We have used a caching bean in this example but you can run any SSJS or Java within the XAgent. It does not need to return a data. Here, you might also use an RPC component.

Comment: but i want to open the link in a new tab. how would that work

Comment: In such a case, you would have two options. First, you would create a intermediate page, an XAgent style page that record which page is clicked and redirect the user to the desired page. Second, you would use a RPC component asynchronously submitting the "page clicked" event while the user navigates to the other page on a new tab. We have implemented the second method on CollaborationToday, I'll update the answer with links.

Comment: Updated the answer. Sorry for my mistake, I looked at the code again, we are not using an RPC component in CT. But it would also be an alternative to our approach.

Comment: creating an intermediate page is no option because notes link shouldnt open in a new tab. only weblinks should. The intermediate page would then overwrite the existing portal

Comment: Then don't use an intermediate page. :) The updated answer is not an intermediate page example.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it. It might also get fixed with an asynchronous call but that also works fine.

Create the link and add a client side on click event. Trigger the click of a button with a one second delay. Webpage opens and SSJS fires afterwards. See attached example:

`<xp:link escape="true" text="Link" value="Link">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[id="#{javascript:MenuDocument.getDocument().getUniversalID()}";
                        setTimeout(function(){$(".Button"+id).click();},1000);
            ]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:link>
        <xp:button value="log" id="logbutton"
            style="display:none;">
            <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Button"+MenuDocument.getDocument().getUniversalID()}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Recent">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://do whatever you want to do}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>`